# IntelliJ IDEA проблема с компиляцией

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Доброго времени суток! Нашел я проект на GitHub https://github.com/bither/bither-desktop-java , импортировал как gradle project в intellij по рекомендациям автора, но вылезают ошибки. Вроде что-то с зависимостями, но куда нажимать чтобы было хорошо не пойму. Прошу, помогите запустить проект.

[image: структура]
[image: build]
[image: sync]
[image: terminal build]
[image: jdk]
[image: jdk]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте текст ошибки в виде текста, а не в виде картинки.

Comment: Какой текст ошибок и зачем? У него стандартные джавоский классы не найдены, а из консоли всё компилируется.

Answer (score 2):

1. В свойствах укажи путь к JDK / JRE.
2. Полужи проект куда-нибудь, где в пути не будет кириллицы - на консоле явно видно, что с кодировкой что-то не то...

Comment: Запустил проект по новой, пути без кириллицы эффекта не дали. Мне кажется я зависимости не правильно выставил (1 изображение).

Comment: Продолжает выдавать: 
Warning:Unable to make the module: bither-desktop-java-master, related gradle configuration was not found. Please, re-import the Gradle project and try again.

И еще Gradle 'bither-desktop-java-master' project refresh failed
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: А первый пункт выполнил?

Comment: Да, скрины приложу выше

Comment: @darkska92 не прикладывайте скрины ошибок. скопируйте текст ошибки и вставьте в вопрос, текстом, а не картинкой